# How best to convert a byte[] array to a string buffer

Tags: java

I have a number of byte[] array variables I need to convert to string buffers.

is there a method for this type of conversion ?

Thanks

Thank you all for your responses..However I didn't make myself clear....
I'm using some byte[] arrays pre-defined as public static "under" the class declaration 
for my java program. these "fields" are reused during the "life" of the process. 
As the program issues status messages, (written to a file) I've defined a string buffer
(mesg_data) that used to format a status message. 
So as the program executes 
I tried msg2 = String(byte_array2) 
I get a compiler error:
cannot find symbol
symbol  : method String(byte[])
location: class APPC_LU62.java.LU62XnsCvr
         convrsID  =  String(conversation_ID) ;

example:

```
public class LU62XnsCvr extends Object
           .
           .
static String convrsID ; 
static byte[] conversation_ID = new byte[8] ;
```

So I can't use a "dynamic" define of a string variable because the same variable is used
in multiple occurances.

I hope I made myself clear 
Thanks ever so much

Guy

Comment: you need the byte string representation? or each byte represent a char?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String s = new String(myByteArray, "UTF-8");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Because of the missing character encoding?

Comment: Yes, you should specify the character encoding.  If you want one byte maps to one character, then use the "US-ASCII" encoding.  If you don't specify the encoding, you may get different results in different environments.  In any case specifying "US-ASCII" makes it clear.

Answer (score 5):

There is a constructor that a byte array and encoding:

```
 byte[] bytes = new byte[200];
 //...

 String s = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

In order to translate bytes to characters you need to specify encoding: the scheme by which sequences (typically of length 1,2 or 3) of 0-255 values (that is: sequence of bytes) are mapped to characters. UTF-8 is probably the best bet as a default.

Answer (score 3):

You can turn it to a `String` directly

```
byte[] bytearray
....
String mystring = new String(bytearray)
```

and then to convert to a `StringBuffer`

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(mystring)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
str = new String(bytes)
```

By thewhat the code above does is to create a java String (i.e. UTF-16) with the default platform character encoding.

If the byte array was created from a string encoded in the platform default character encoding this will work well.

If not you need to specify the correct character encoding (Charset) as

```
String str = new String (byte [] bytes, Charset charset)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on the character encoding, but you want:

```
String value = new String(bytes, "US-ASCII");
```

This would work for US-ASCII values.

See [`Charset`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) for other valid character encodings (e.g., UTF-8)